# ¿Cómo hacer clickeables 2 o más elementos en una CardView?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, cardview

en el siguiente enlace les muestro como implemento yo una lista de Cardviews

> https://github.com/JorgeIPN7/RecyclerViewT1

**Puse en comentarios lo que estaba intentando para hacer más limpio el código pero no me quedo**

Mi duda está en:

- MyAdapter.java
- MainActivity.java

Quisiera saber si la forma en lo que lo estoy haciendo es la correcta o cómo podría mejorar mi implementación... en ocasiones cuando reciclo el código en diferentes activities se hace muy difícil de leer.

Quisiera ser más especifico pero no sé como, mi duda principalmente es que estoy creando muchos **...new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener()...** en mi ActivityMain y quisiera hacer más legible el código.

Si alguien tiene una mejor implementación podría hacer una aportación o pasarme el ejemplo, por favor.

Comment: Hola @JorgeLópez , Bienvenido a [StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por la pagina para poder ganar tu primera medalla, y ver [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para hacer un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y la comunidad acepte de buena forma tu pregunta

Comment: @JorgeLopez    te sirvio la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

> Basándome en tu pregunta utilizare la palabra **elemento** para referirme a las vistas, tales como el `TextView`, pero su correcto nombre es **componente**.

Bueno mira, lo que tienes que hacer es implementar la interfaz `OnClickListener` en la clase `ViewHolder` de tu adaptador. Con el método `setOnClickListener()` de los elementos, haces que todos apunten al método `onClick()` de la interfaz `OnClickListener`.

```
ll_1.setOnClickListener(this);
tv_pais.setOnClickListener(this);
```

De esta manera todos los eventos onClick de los elementos estarán apuntando a un solo método, el método `onClick()` de la interfaz `OnCLickListener`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // Código a ejecutar
}
```

El método `onClick()` de la interfaz recibe un parámetro de tipo `View`, este parámetro recibe las vistas de todos los elementos que estén apuntando a el. Al hacer click en un elemento, el parámetro `view` recibe la vista del elemento clickcleado y a través de este se puede saber cual elemento fue clickcleado. Utilizando los métodos del parámetro `view` se pueden obtener todas las propiedades de los elementos que estén apuntando al método `onClick()`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId(); // Obtiene el id del elemento clickleado
    String texto = view.getText(); // Obtiene el texto del elemento clickleado
    int color = view.getBackgroundColor(); // Obtiene el color de fondo del elemento clickleado
}
```

Dentro del método `onClick()` debes llamar el método `onItemClickListener()` de la interfaz `OnItemClickListener` que creaste en el adaptador. A este método le debes pasar como parámetro, el parámetro `view` del método `onClick()`. Este parámetro lo utilizaras en la implementación de la interfaz `OnItemClickListener` para saber a cual elemento le hicieron click.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    listener.onItemClickListener(view);
}
```

Para saber a cual elemento le hicieron click puedes utilizar el método `getId()` del parámetro `view`.

```
...
adapter= new MyAdapter(paises, R.layout.cardview, this, new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position) {

                if (id == R.id.ll_1) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Han clickcleado el LinearLayout izquierdo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
...
```

### Ejemplo

#### MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    List<Pais> lista;
    private int layout;
    private Activity activity;
    private static OnItemClickListener listener;

    public MyAdapter(List<Pais> lista, int layout, Activity activity, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.lista = lista;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listener = listener;
     }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.onBind(lista.get(position).getNombre());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }


   public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        LinearLayout ll_1, ll_2, ll_3;
        TextView tv_pais;

      public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            ll_1= (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_1);
            ll_2= (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_2);
            ll_3= (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_3);
            tv_pais= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_pais);

            // Apuntas todos los eventos onClick de los elementos al método
            // onClick() de la interfaz OnClickListener
            ll_1.setOnClickListener(this);
            ll_2.setOnClickListener(this);
            ll_3.setOnClickListener(this);
            tv_pais.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

      public void onBind(String nombre) {
            tv_pais.setText(nombre);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Llamas el método onItemClickListener() de la interfaz OnItemClickListener
            listener.onItemClickListener(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }


 public interface OnItemClickListener{

        // Este método recibe como parámetro la vista del elemento seleccionado
        void onItemClickListener(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Pais> paises;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        paises= new ArrayList<>();
        paises.add(new Pais(1, "México"));
        paises.add(new Pais(2, "Italia"));

        Log.i("Paises", "" + paises.size());

        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter= new MyAdapter(paises, R.layout.cardview, this, new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View view, int position) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item #" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Identifica el elemento clickcleado
                switch (view.getId()) {

                    case R.id.ll_1:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.ll_2:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.ll_3:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                    case R.id.tv_pais:

                        TextView textView = (TextView) view;

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, textView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }

            }
        });

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Puedes encontrar el codigo completo de este ejemplo en mi repositorio de GitLab:
[RespuestasStackOverflow](https://gitlab.com/david-minaya/RespuestasStackOverflow)

Comment: El metodo OnItemClickListener no lleva el parametro int position, me tira error.

Comment: Eso es verdad. Ya edito la respuesta. El error es porque se me olvido pasar la posición del item presionado, con el método `getAdapterPosition()`.