# ¿Como hago un evento a un View especifico en un RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el `onCreate()` de la actividad que contiene al `RecyclerView`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_courses);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCourses);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ArrayList<Course> datos = new ArrayList<>();
        datos.add(new Course("Relational databases", 500,
                "A complete course about relational databases.", R.drawable.bbdd));
        datos.add(new Course("OOP", 500,
                "A complete course about objects oriented programming.", R.drawable.objetos));
        datos.add(new Course("Android", 0,
                "A complete course about Android.", R.drawable.android));

        adapter = new CoursesAdapter(datos);
        adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch(view.getId()){
                    case R.id.buttonBuy:{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Seleccion: "+recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
                            ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Y el codigo de mi adaptador con el `View.OnClickListener` implentado es este:

```
    public class CoursesAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CoursesAdapter.ViewHolder>
                implements View.OnClickListener{
        ArrayList<Course> dataSet;
        private View.OnClickListener listener;
        public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener l){
            this.listener = l;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(listener != null){
                listener.onClick(view);
            }
        }

        static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            TextView title;
            TextView description;
            TextView cost;
            ImageView image;
            Button buttonBuy, buttonSeeMore;
            Context context;
            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                context = itemView.getContext();
                title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
                description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
                cost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCost);
                image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCover);
            }

        }

    public CoursesAdapter(ArrayList<Course> dataSet){
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_course, parent, false);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(dataSet.get(position).getName());
        if(dataSet.get(position).getCost() == 0){
            holder.cost.setText("FREE");
        }else{
            holder.cost.setText("$"+dataSet.get(position).getCost());
        }
        holder.description.setText(dataSet.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.image.setImageResource(dataSet.get(position).getCover());
        //events
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

El adapter funciona bien, pero intento decirle un elemento especifico (`R.id.buttonBuy`) en el `setOnClickListener` pero no funciona.

Acabo de comprobar que si sirve el `onClick`, pero quiero especificar un elemento (como un `TexView`, etc) dentro del CardView que es el `item.xml` asociado a los elementos del `RecyclerView`.

Comment: En esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104681/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-clickeables-2-o-m%C3%A1s-elementos-en-una-cardview/104728#104728) puedes encontrar mi respuesta que da solución a un problema muy similar al tuyo.

Comment: donde tienes `//events` agrega el onClick listenera los elementos que quieras en especifico `holder.title.setOnClickListener(this)`, esto te agregaria un listener al `TextView title`

Answer (score 1):

Modifica el click listener para que apunte al UI que desees:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(dataSet.get(position).getName());
        if(dataSet.get(position).getCost() == 0){
            holder.cost.setText("FREE");
        }else{
            holder.cost.setText("$"+dataSet.get(position).getCost());
        }
      holder.description.setText(dataSet.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.image.setImageResource(dataSet.get(position).getCover());
        //events
       holder.description.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Me base en lo que le respondieron a David aquí [en esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104681/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-clickeables-2-o-m%C3%A1s-elementos-en-una-cardview) y así quedó la clase que contiene el RecyclerView

```
public class ViewCoursesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private CourseAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_courses);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCourses);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        ArrayList<Course> datos = new ArrayList<>();
        datos.add(new Course("Relational databases", 500,
                "A complete course about relational databases.", R.drawable.bbdd));
        datos.add(new Course("OOP", 500,
                "A complete course about objects oriented programming.", R.drawable.objetos));
        datos.add(new Course("Android", 0,
                "A complete course about Android.", R.drawable.android));

        adapter = new CourseAdapter(datos, R.layout.card_course,
                this, new CourseAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClickListener(View view) {
                    switch (view.getId()){
                        case R.id.buttonBuy:{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Funciona", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Y el adapter así, donde implementé el OnItemClickListener en el ViewHolder, etc.

```
public class CourseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<Course> dataSet;
    private int layout;
    private Activity activity;
    private static OnItemClickListener listener;

    public CourseAdapter(ArrayList<Course> dataSet, int layout, Activity activity, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public CourseAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CourseAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.title.setText(dataSet.get(position).getName());
        if(dataSet.get(position).getCost() == 0){
            holder.cost.setText("FREE");
        }else{
            holder.cost.setText("$"+dataSet.get(position).getCost());
        }
        holder.description.setText(dataSet.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.image.setImageResource(dataSet.get(position).getCover());
        //events
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        TextView cost;
        ImageView image;
        Button buttonBuy, buttonSeeMore;
        Context context;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
            cost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCost);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCover);
            buttonBuy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonBuy);
            buttonSeeMore = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSeeMore);
            buttonBuy.setOnClickListener(this);
            buttonSeeMore.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Llamas el método onItemClickListener() de la interfaz OnItemClickListener
            listener.onItemClickListener(view);
        }
    }
    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        // Este método recibe como parámetro la vista del elemento seleccionado
        void onItemClickListener(View view);
    }
}
```

Funciona como quería, sin embargo ahora me surge el problema de identificar a que CardView pertenece cada vista, lo cual postearé en otra pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

te faltan varias cosas para que funcione como necesitas.
Inicialmente en la clase `static class ViewHolder...` el botón `buttonBuy` esta declarado pero no lo inicializaste en el constructor.

En el método `onCreateViewHolder` elimina la línea `view.setOnClickListener(this);` ya no escuchará los click sobre el View.

Si quieres y te recomiendo que el adapter no escuche eventos por lo tanto quitalo del `implements` al igual que el atributo listener del adapter.

Finalmente en el método `onBindViewHolder` has holder.buttonBuy.setOnClickListener....

Luego es posible que en el onClick necesites abrir una actividad o incluso interactuar con otros elementos de la actividad que están fuera del adapter. Si fuera ese tu caso, te recomiendo utilizar un callback (interface) en el Constructor del adapter lo declaras e implementas en la actividad y lo pasas al constructor del adapter. En el onClick del adapter lo ejecutas callback.miOnClick por ejemplo y eso se ejecuta en la actividad.