# Mostrar un DialogFragment desde un Adapter RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, adapter, android-context

tengo un problema al tratar de mostrar un Dialogfragment desde un Adapter.

Normalmente lo he hecho llamando al `parent.Context` del `inflater`, de la siguiente manera:

```
public class MiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MiAdapter.adapterHolder>{
Context context;
List<lista> lista;

public MiAdapter (List<lista> lista){
    this.lista = lista;
}

@Override
public MiAdapter.adapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rec_lista, parent, false);
    MiAdapter.adapterHolderholder = new MiAdapter.adapterHolder(v);
    context = parent.getContext();
    return holder;
}.....
```

En el `onBindViewHolder` es donde muestro el `DialogFragment` después de un click.

```
 FragmentManager manager= ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                            OtroFragment manager= new ShPerfil();                      
                            OtroFragment.show(manager, "Otro");
```

Sin embargo en algunas ocasiones me genera el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ContextThemeWrapper cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
                                                                       at com.miapp.Adapters.MiAdapter$1.onClick(MiAdapter.java:54)
                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213)
                                                                       at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11074)
```

Después de investigar un rato encontré algo de utilidad, la respuesta que esta en este [enlace.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135697/how-to-get-context-when-you-call-method-in-different-class?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Sin embargo al implementarlo la aplicación muere siempre que intento mostrar el `DialogFragment` con el siguiente error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: ccom.miapp.MyContext cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

Alguien podría ayudarme a solucionar este problema? no se si pueda mostrar el DialogFragment de otra manera o obtener el Context de otra forma.

Gracias amigos!

Comment: eso debe hacerse con una interface desde la activity/fragment que llama al adapter

Comment: Probaré hacerlo con una interface, estaba pensando en eso también

Comment: un buen ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104681/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-clickeables-2-o-m%C3%A1s-elementos-en-una-cardview/104728#104728

Answer (score 1):

La solución era más sencilla, simplemente pasar el Context de la Activity o del DialogFragment algo así:

```
 public class MiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MiAdapter.adapterHolder> {
Context mContext;
List<list> list;

public MiAdapter(Context context, List<list> list) {
    this.list = list;
    mContext = context;
}
```

al ser desde un DialogFragment convertir el Context a appCompatActivity.