# Cómo puedo obtener el dato del objeto que selecciono en un RecyclerView dentro de un Fragment?

Tags: java, android

Quiero obtener el dato del objeto que selecciono en la lista del RecyclerView. ¿Cómo podría obtener ese dato seleccionado en la lista?...

Este es mi RecyclerView

```
//ESTO ES PARA EL RecyclerView

        recyclerTipoAtencion.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        adapterTipoAtencion = new AdapterTipoAtencion(usuarios);

        adapterTipoAtencion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Selección: "
                //        + usuarios.get(recyclerEmpresas.getChildAdapterPosition(view))
                //        .getUsuario() +  usuarios.get(recyclerEmpresas.getChildAdapterPosition(view))
                //        .getLogo(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                TipoAtencion1 = usuarios.get(recyclerTipoAtencion.getChildAdapterPosition(view))
                        .getTipoAtencion1();
                TipoAtencion2 = usuarios.get(recyclerTipoAtencion.getChildAdapterPosition(view))
                        .getTipoAtencion2();

                BusinessFragment bsfragment = new BusinessFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();            
                bundle.putString("TipoAtencion1", TipoAtencion1);
                bundle.putString("TipoAtencion2", TipoAtencion2);
                bundle.putString("TipoAtencionSelected", TipoAtencionSelected);
                bsfragment.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentManager FM = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();

                FT.replace(R.id.contenedor, bsfragment);
                FT.addToBackStack(null);

                FT.commit();

            }
        });

        recyclerTipoAtencion.setAdapter(adapterTipoAtencion);

        final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        //database.getReference().getRoot().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        mDatabase.child("z Empresas " + País).child(Ciudad).child(TipodeEmpresa).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                usuarios.removeAll(usuarios);
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot:
                        dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Usuario usuario = snapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);
                    usuarios.add(usuario);

                }
                adapterTipoAtencion.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //ESTO ES PARA EL RecyclerView
```

Y este es mi Adapter

```
public class AdapterTipoAtencion extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTipoAtencion.TipoAtencionViewHolder>
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    List<Usuario> usuarios;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;

    private String tap1, tap2;
    private TextView textviewtipoatencion1, textviewtipoatencion2;
    private View viewtipoatencion1, viewtipoatencion2;

    public AdapterTipoAtencion(List<Usuario> usuarios) {
        this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }

    @Override
    public TipoAtencionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_recycler_tipoatencion, parent, false);
        TipoAtencionViewHolder holder = new TipoAtencionViewHolder(v);

        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        textviewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion1);
        textviewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion2);
        viewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion1);
        viewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion2);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TipoAtencionViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Usuario usuario = usuarios.get(position);

        tap1 = usuario.getTipoAtencion1();
        tap2 = usuario.getTipoAtencion2();

        if (tap1 == null){
            textviewtipoatencion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            viewtipoatencion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion1.setText(usuario.getTipoAtencion1());
        }

        if (tap2 == null){
            textviewtipoatencion2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            viewtipoatencion2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion2.setText(usuario.getTipoAtencion2());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return usuarios.size();
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onClick(view);
        }
    }

    public static class TipoAtencionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textviewtipoatencion1, textviewtipoatencion2;
        private View viewtipoatencion1, viewtipoatencion2;

        public TipoAtencionViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textviewtipoatencion1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion1);
            textviewtipoatencion2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion2);
            viewtipoatencion1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion1);
            viewtipoatencion2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion2);

        }

    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme...

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda!

Comment: Como se llama la actividad que contiene los fragmentos y como se llaman los fragmentos. Y también agrega el adaptador del recyclerView.

Comment: @DavidMinaya hola amigo, sólo necesito obtener el dato del objeto que selecciono en la lista del recyclerview... Lo que pasa es que tengo varias opciones dentro del recyclerview y necesito que obtenga el valor solo del que yo selecciono.

Comment: Necesito que proporciones más información para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @DavidMinaya arriba agregue el Adapter de mi RecyclerView, muchas gracias amigo!

Comment: Esta respuesta que le di a otro usuario te puede ser de ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104681/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-clickeables-2-o-m%C3%A1s-elementos-en-una-cardview/104728#104728

Comment: @DavidMinaya creo que podría servirme esa respuesta, más tarde llegare a implementarlo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, amigo.

Comment: Has podido solucionar el problema?

Comment: @DavidMinaya Si amigo, gracias a tu comentario pude solucionar una parte de lo que necesito, el problema que tengo ahora es el siguiente... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171021/enviar-valores-desde-un-fragment-a-un-adapter

Comment: @DavidMinaya El problema que tengo ahora en el siguiente link es que en la parte de arriba del Adapter recojo los datos que envío desde el Fragment sin ningum problema, pero al querer usarlos en el "public static class TipoAtencionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener", estos me los lee como null.