# Enviar valores desde un Fragment a un Adapter

Tags: java, android

Quiero enviar variables desde un Fragment hacia un Adapter...

Aquí están los valores del Fragment que deseo enviar y algún otro código. Los valores que deseo enviar son País, Ciudad, TipodeEmpresa, EmpresaUser y Logo.

```
 País = getArguments().getString("País");
    Ciudad = getArguments().getString("Ciudad");
    TipodeEmpresa = getArguments().getString("TipodeEmpresa");
    EmpresaUser = getArguments().getString("EmpresaUser");
    Logo = getArguments().getString("Logo");

    //ESTO ES PARA EL RecyclerView

    recyclerTipoAtencion.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    adapterTipoAtencion = new AdapterTipoAtencion(usuarios);

    recyclerTipoAtencion.setAdapter(adapterTipoAtencion);
```

Y este es mi Adapter Completo... Sin embargo necesito enviar los datos hacia el "public static class TipoAtencionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener", ya que si los envío al Adapter en general, no me reconoce las variables en el TipoAtencionViewHolder... Necesito poder usar las variables del Fragment dentro del OnClick de mi Adapter, al final del código.

```
public class AdapterTipoAtencion extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTipoAtencion.TipoAtencionViewHolder> {

    List<Usuario> usuarios;

    private String tap1, tap2, retap1, retap2;
    private TextView textviewtipoatencion1, textviewtipoatencion2;
    private View viewtipoatencion1, viewtipoatencion2;

    public AdapterTipoAtencion(List<Usuario> usuarios) { this.usuarios = usuarios; }

    @Override
    public TipoAtencionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.row_recycler_tipoatencion, parent, false);
        TipoAtencionViewHolder holder = new TipoAtencionViewHolder(v);

        textviewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion1);
        textviewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion2);
        viewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion1);
        viewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion2);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TipoAtencionViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Usuario usuario = usuarios.get(position);
        tap1 = usuario.getTipoAtencion1();
        tap2 = usuario.getTipoAtencion2();
        if (tap1 == null) {
            textviewtipoatencion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            viewtipoatencion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion1.setText(usuario.getTipoAtencion1());
            retap1 = textviewtipoatencion1.getText().toString();
        }

        if (tap2 == null) {
            textviewtipoatencion2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            viewtipoatencion2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.textviewtipoatencion2.setText(usuario.getTipoAtencion2());
            retap2 = textviewtipoatencion2.getText().toString();
        }

        holder.setOnClickListeners();

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return usuarios.size(); }

    public static class TipoAtencionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private Context context;
        private TextView textviewtipoatencion1, textviewtipoatencion2;
        private View viewtipoatencion1, viewtipoatencion2;
        private Button btnDetails, btnEditHeader;

        public TipoAtencionViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            context = v.getContext();
            textviewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion1);
            textviewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion2);
            viewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion1);
            viewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion2);
            btnDetails = v.findViewById(R.id.btnDetails);
            btnEditHeader = v.findViewById(R.id.btnEditHeader);
        }

        void setOnClickListeners(){
            textviewtipoatencion1.setOnClickListener(this);
            textviewtipoatencion2.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnDetails.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnEditHeader.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.textview_tipoatencion1:

                    String txttap1 = textviewtipoatencion1.getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Tipo de atención: " + txttap1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.textview_tipoatencion2:

                    String txttap2 = textviewtipoatencion2.getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Tipo de atención: " + txttap2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme... Muchas gracias por todo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como menciona arriba, puedes pasar por el constructor del adapter:

```
private String Pais;
private String Ciudad;
private String TipodeEmpresa;
private String EmpresaUser;
private String Logo;

public AdapterTipoAtencion(List<Usuario> usuarios, String Pais, String Ciudad, String TipodeEmpresa, String EmpresaUser, String Logo) { 
   this.usuarios = usuarios; 
   this.Pais = Pais;
   this.Ciudad = Ciudad;
   this.TipodeEmpresa = TipodeEmpresa;
   this.EmpresaUser= EmpresaUser;
   this.Logo = Logo;
}
```

ahora, tambien puedes implementar el onClickListener en el metodo `onBindViewHolder()`

no necesariamente en el ViewHolder, entonces podria quedar asi

```
public class AdapterTipoAtencion extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterTipoAtencion.TipoAtencionViewHolder> {

    List<Usuario> usuarios;

    private String tap1, tap2, retap1, retap2;

    private String Pais;
    private String Ciudad;
    private String TipodeEmpresa;
    private String EmpresaUser;
    private String Logo;

    public AdapterTipoAtencion(List<Usuario> usuarios, String Pais, String Ciudad, String TipodeEmpresa, String EmpresaUser, String Logo) { 
      this.usuarios = usuarios; 
      this.Pais = Pais;
      this.Ciudad = Ciudad;
      this.TipodeEmpresa = TipodeEmpresa;
      this.EmpresaUser= EmpresaUser;
      this.Logo = Logo;
}

@Override
public TipoAtencionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.row_recycler_tipoatencion, parent, false);
    TipoAtencionViewHolder holder = new TipoAtencionViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TipoAtencionViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Usuario usuario = usuarios.get(position);
    tap1 = usuario.getTipoAtencion1();
    tap2 = usuario.getTipoAtencion2();
    if (tap1 == null) {
        holder.textviewtipoatencion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.viewtipoatencion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.textviewtipoatencion1.setText(usuario.getTipoAtencion1());
        retap1 = holder.textviewtipoatencion1.getText().toString();
    }

    if (tap2 == null) {
        holder.textviewtipoatencion2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.viewtipoatencion2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.textviewtipoatencion2.setText(usuario.getTipoAtencion2());
        retap2 = holder.textviewtipoatencion2.getText().toString();
    }

    holder.textviewtipoatencion1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String txttap1 = holder.textviewtipoatencion1.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Tipo de atención: " + txttap1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //puedes usar el las variables que pasaste en el constructor
        }
    });
    holder.textviewtipoatencion2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String txttap2 = textviewtipoatencion2.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Tipo de atención: " + txttap2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //puedes usar el las variables que pasaste en el constructor
        }
    });
    holder.btnDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //implementar evento click
            //puedes usar el las variables que pasaste en el constructor
        }
    });
    holder.btnEditHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //implementar evento click
            //puedes usar el las variables que pasaste en el constructor
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() { return usuarios.size(); }

public static class TipoAtencionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context context;
    private TextView textviewtipoatencion1, textviewtipoatencion2;
    private View viewtipoatencion1, viewtipoatencion2;
    private Button btnDetails, btnEditHeader;

    public TipoAtencionViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        context = v.getContext();
        textviewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion1);
        textviewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.textview_tipoatencion2);
        viewtipoatencion1 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion1);
        viewtipoatencion2 = v.findViewById(R.id.view_tipoatencion2);
        btnDetails = v.findViewById(R.id.btnDetails);
        btnEditHeader = v.findViewById(R.id.btnEditHeader);
    }

}
}
```

ademas tenias código redundante en la parte de `onCreateViewHolder()` ligabas otra vez las vistas, ya las tienes en el ViewHolder asi que no es necesario.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigos, con esto y con lo de @Jorgesys pude solucionar el problema. Son unos genios!!

Answer (score 1):

De la misma forma que envias el valor de usuarios a tu `Adapter`, puedes modificar el método para que este reciba otros valores:

```
adapterTipoAtencion = new AdapterTipoAtencion(usuarios);
```

ejemplo:

```
private String Pais;
private String Ciudad;
private String TipodeEmpresa;
private String EmpresaUser;
private String Logo;

public AdapterTipoAtencion(List<Usuario> usuarios, String Pais, String Ciudad, String TipodeEmpresa, String EmpresaUser, String Logo) { 
   this.usuarios = usuarios; 
   this.Pais = Pais;
   this.Ciudad = Ciudad;
   this.TipodeEmpresa = TipodeEmpresa;
   this.EmpresaUser= EmpresaUser;
   this.Logo = Logo;
}
```

e instanciarías el `Adapter` de esta forma:

```
 adapterTipoAtencion = new AdapterTipoAtencion(usuarios, País, Ciudad, TipodeEmpresa, EmpresaUser, Logo ) ;
```

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, sí, ese es el método que debería funcionar, pero lo que pasa es que los datos los quiero recibir en la parte de abajo de mi Adapter, donde está mi (public static class TipoAtencionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener) y al instanciar el public AdapterTipoAtencion me lo deja en rojo y no puedo implementarlo... Ese es mi problema. Y si recibo los datos en la parte de arriba de mi Adapter no los puedo usar abajo en (public static class TipoAtencionViewHolder), ya que recoge los valores como null.

Comment: en la parte de arriba del Adapter recojo los datos sin ningum problema, pero al querer usarlos en el "public static class TipoAtencionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener", estos me los lee como null.